# How to debug amazon lambda function in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, aws-lambda

Im working on a .net core aws lambda project. And I cannot debug it. I tried to debug but i had an error like

> Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry
>   point.

I added a static main method into function.cs class and added '**"debugType": "portable","emitEntryPoint": true**' lines to ***project.json*** file then;

I had an error like **project does not contain an entry point and cannot be started directly. In order to debug this project, "emitEntryPoint":true needs to be added...**

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you create a test class ( a public class with [TestClass] attribute ) and then add to it a test method ( [TestMethod] attribute ) which will execute your lambda function with the relevant input.

This way you'll be able to debug your lambda easily.

I suppose you write unit tests for your lambda's anyways :)

Comment: Thanks for advice that worked! I used this article to create mstest library for .net core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/testing/using-mstest-on-windows

Comment: Would appreciate you accepting my answer then :)